# matlab imread error using the executable

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-deployment

I have a matlab function img_process that requires the following parameters : image_name intensity and boundary, so if I run the following on my matlab console :

```
img_process 'pic1.png' 0.01 1
```

This will run the function and the image will be processed and I will get a result printed out.

Now I have compiled the script as a windows standalone app named img_process_test. I then try to run it from my command line in windows from the distrib folder like :

```
img_process_test 'pic1.png' 0.01 1
```

and it will tell me that `error imread , file was not found`.

I did try to place the pic1.png in the distrib and src and the img_process_test folders but still it will not work.

Any idea ?
Thank you for looking

Comment: Great that you found the answer! The best way to go now is to write your solution as an answer to your own question and accept it (and remove it from the question). So people know this answer has been solved and it keeps the record clean. Thanks!

Comment: would be great but I cannot do it because my reputation is less than 100...

Comment: I'm surprised, did you actually try? You should always be able to answer your own question. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: weird, I did try before but it didn`t work.. now it works :-) thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this. I found a good help here : http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2010/12/21/strings-and-numbers-as-arguments/

in case someone stumbles into this and would like to know a workaround.